# 2 stage Pi type LC filter

Tags: passive-filter

I need to design a 2 stage LC filter for operating in the range of DC - 70 Mhz frequency.

[image]

Can someone provide some inputs on how to get started?

Comment: That looks pretty good so far. What exactly do you need to know?

Comment: I need to know the values of each component and how to calculate and how to validate calculated values?

Comment: Install LTspice, do an AC analysis to obtain a bode plot and tweak the values so you obtain the desired result

Comment: What does C1 bring to the party when you connect a pure voltage source to the left side (presumed to be the input)?

Comment: @Huisman gave you stage 2 : that's how you validate. Stage 1 is to learn basic filter design, specify what you want the filter to do, and use filter design equations to satisfy that specification as a starting point. They come down to how component impedances vary with frequency. You have to match the filter to the source impedance driving it, and the load impedance on its output. Without understanding this, sims won't do you much good.

Answer (score 1):

Most filter applets assume a linear voltage source or current source. Since the **input** source of a *rectifier* is non-linear in this case, these applets are not appropriate.
The rectifier (diodes?) should be included in a simulation. The signal source might best be included as a Thevenin or Norton equivalent circuit. For example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmmLhJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Rsource** is not a physical resistor, but is an estimate of the impedance of the signal source. For example, a resonant dipole antenna would make **Rsource=70 ohms**. An estimate of **Rload** must be made as well. It might be derived from DC voltage and DC current required.
A simulation must account for the rectifier's non-linear behavior. In SPICE, it must be a **transient analysis** rather than an **AC sweep**.

Comment: What is the rectifier for here?

Comment: @BrianDrummond OP's schematic has *voltage from rectifier* as the signal source. Since the rectifier was not included in the schematic, I have made an assumption, choosing the simplest possible rectifier type.